# Looking for a method to maximize a sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization, summation

I need a method to find a sequence $(n_k)_k$ of positive real numbers  that maximizes the following sum:
$$
\sum^{+\infty}_{k=0}(a_k\, n_k-n_k^2\,e^{-r\,k}),
$$
where $(a_k)_k$ is a given sequence and $r$ is a data.

Comment: The problem appears to be decomposable in the variables $\{n_k\}$, so it suffices to maximize each term of the sum, which is a quadratic, with respect to the corresponding variable ($n_k$).

Comment: @madnessweasley Sorry, but I think this doesn't work since the maximization of the sum is not equivalent to maximizing each term, provided that the terms of the sum are not necessarily positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stationary points are computed as

$$
\nabla\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_kn_k-n^2_ke^{-r k}) = 0
$$

giving

$$
a_k - 2n_k e^{-r k} = 0, \ \ k = 0,1,\cdots
$$

or

$$
n_k = \frac{1}{2}a_k e^{r k}
$$

giving

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_kn_k-n^2_ke^{-r k}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k^2e^{r k}
$$